# How to connect the replica set from Java using MongoOption

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Currently my Code is like this

```
List<MongoCredential> creds = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
creds.add(MongoCredential.createCredential(username, dbName, password.toCharArray()));
MongoClientOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
optionsBuilder.connectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(connectionTimeOut));
optionsBuilder.serverSelectionTimeout(Integer.parseInt(serverSelectionTimeOut));
optionsBuilder.socketTimeout(Integer.parseInt(socketTimeOut));
optionsBuilder.connectionsPerHost(Integer.parseInt(connections));
MongoClientOptions options = optionsBuilder.build();
mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostname, Integer.parseInt(port)), creds, options);
```

It is connecting to single MongoDB but i want to connect the replica set of MongoDB. Could you please help me to connect the replica set of MongoDB

Comment: Technically, simply supplying any more than one node as a `ServerAdress` initiates a replica set connection. As long as one of the supplied addresses is actually a replica set member that is. See [Connect to a Replica Set](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/#connect-to-a-replica-set) in the reference documentation. The difference being only 1 address without a specific "option" set ( URI only ) just treats the member as a standalone connection. Same goes for all drivers.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please  conform one thing while connecting using replica Set  "credentialsList(username, dbName, password)" are  same for all  mongoDB availaible in ReplicaSet (or) not.

Comment: There is only one set of credentials. If you look at the provided documentation it shows in all forms that there are multiple hosts and one set of credentials.